# SQL to get Count of Members in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Group` table with the columns `GroupId` and `GroupName`. Also there is another table called `Group_Student` which keeps track of which group a student belongs. It contains the columns `GroupId` (foreign key to the `Group` table) and `StudentId`.

I would like to know on how I can write a SQL query which lists the `GroupName`, `GroupId` and the number of students in each group.

Example, if the `Group_Student` table contains the following entries

```
GroupId   StudentId  
-------------------
  1          2 
  1          3 
  2          4
```

Then the SQL query should produce the following output

```
GroupName    MemberCount
------------------------
   ABC           1   
   DEF           2
```

Kindly let me know how I can write the SQL for this. I'm using SQL Server 2005. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sql fiddle of this working

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f8a5/2/0

```
select 
   groupname, [group].groupid, count(*) as 'MemberCount'
from [group]
inner join group_student on [group].groupid = group_student.groupid
group by groupname, [group].groupid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GroupName, Group.GroupID, COUNT(StudentId) AS MemberCount 
FROM Group 
INNER JOIN Group_Student ON Group.GroupID = Group_Student.GroupID 
GROUP BY Group.GroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below:

It will join the two tables, and then add a count to it. The `GROUP BY` clause ensures that the values for the count are grouped by `GroupName` and `GroupId`

```
SELECT GroupName, a.GroupId, count(StudentId) "MemberCount"
FROM Group a
JOIN Group_student b on a.GroupId= b.GroupId
GROUP BY GroupName, a.GroupId
```